# MySQL - Average by columns in group by clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do aggregations based on columns specified in MySQL query. Here's some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (id CHAR(10), name CHAR(10), price INT, cat INT, size INT);

INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name, price, cat, size) 
VALUES ('2065511307', 'abc', 2449, 1, 600), 
       ('65fH72', 'bcd', 4395, 1, 851), 
       ('65fH72', 'bcd', 4995, 2, 985),
       ('65fH72', 'bcd', 4678, 1, 865);
```

I'd like to group by `id` and `cat` columns and compute the `avg` of `price` and `size` columns. When I run the query, I don't get the results I expect.

```
    SELECT id, cat, AVG(price) AS avg_price, AVG(size) AS avg_size
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY id, cat
    HAVING avg_price <= 10000
```

The results I expect to see:

[image: grouped-avg]

Comment: As clearly explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data. No one can copy/paste data from a picture. Sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: @Stu question has been updated w/ `create` and `insert` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that will get you the correct result.

```
SELECT id, name, ROUND(AVG(price), 0) AS avg_price, cat, ROUND(AVG(size), 0) AS avg_size
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY id, cat
HAVING avg_price <= 10000;
```

Note, you may have to turn the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option off to get this query to run. This also assumes `name` is functionally dependent on `id`.

The query below will work if you are unable to turn the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option off.

```
SELECT id, 
  (SELECT name FROM MyTable AS mt WHERE mt.id=MyTable.id LIMIT 1) AS name,
  ROUND(AVG(price), 0) AS avg_price, cat, ROUND(AVG(size), 0) AS avg_size
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY id, cat
HAVING avg_price <= 10000;
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand your expected output, but this is This MySQL ORDER BY would return all records sorted by the id order, with a secondary sort by cat order.
Therefore, it is linked to two remaining, and it is not one values